# CSS transition animation with tiles layout is it possible to achieve?

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I am trying to create a specific solution for weeks now and I have tried many things but I am just not sure if it is possible at all to achieve. I need your opinions and point me in direction o a correct approach. Following what I am trying to create:

Initially there is a tile layout in which a certain number of cards (say 12) are placed in 4x3 grid:

[image: Initial State]

Now, if user clicks on a tile (Box 3), the state changes to following:

Selected tile is expanded and other tiles get aligned one below another on the right side:
[image]

Challenge is that I want to create a **transition** from every tile's initial state to the state where every tile is aligned one below another on the right. At the same time, when a tile is clicked it is expanded in place. 
Note - there are no sudden change in positions, no reload of page and preferably no JS (I wanted to write a CSS-only solution). Everything smoothly animates to new position. From the second screen if a different tile is selected (from right), then the expanded item will shrink and go in to the right hand stack while the selected item will expand and take place of the currently expanded (B3).

If you could just point me to correct direction it would be great help.

thanks.

Comment: The answer is no. Not with CSS.

Comment: Why downvote?? is this not related to this site or is the question not descriptive enough?

Comment: As stated in the question, I HAVE tried many different things, it is not possible for this question to list everything as the main question now is - Is it possible at all to achieve? for which you already said it isn't and I am also thinking now that it is not possible to achieve without some level of JS.

Comment: AT the beginning B1 is to the leff of B3 at the end to the right How  can you do this smoothly?

Answer (score 0):

You should check css flexbox.
Using the "order" proprety, you could asign order of every box from 2 to 8,
and each time a box is selected, you change it's order to 1 and you also change its size and colour.

However, I don't think you can use 'click' actions with css only.
I would recommend using JS for what you are trying to achieve.

Hope it helps